# Unable to compute graph in Google Earth Engine when trying to compute mODIS NDVI Time series analysis of a small region in Crete, Greece

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis, time-series, chart

I want to make a simple time series analysis of the past 8 years using MODIS data but I'm unable to compute the graph as I get the following message:

> Error generating chart: Collection.first: Projection error: Unable to
> compute intersection of geometries in projections SR-ORG:6974: affine
> [231.65635826395825, 0.0, -2.0015109354E7, 0.0, -231.65635826395834,
> 1.0007554677003E7] and EPSG:4326: affine [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0].

My code is as follows:

```
var startDate = '2015-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';

var images = modis.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate))
print(images);

var scaling = function(image){
  var scaled = image.select('NDVI').divide(10000);
  return scaled.copyProperties(image,['system:index', 'system:time_start'])
}
var scaled_ndvi = images.map(scaling);
print(scaled_ndvi);

var scaled_ndvi = images.map(scaling);
print(scaled_ndvi);
var nd = scaled_ndvi.first().clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(nd,{min:0,max:1,palette:['white','Green']},'NDVI');

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: scaled_ndvi,
  regions:roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 250
});
print(chart);
```

Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Can you share your `geometry` object?

Comment: Could you share your code through the get_link button in the code editor?

Answer (score 0):

use regions:roi.geometry().bounds() in the chart function.

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: scaled_ndvi,
regions:roi.geometry().bounds(),
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 250
});